# Can any row of Electrum be my Bitcoin Wallet address

Tags: wallet, electrum

I just installed Electrum 4.3.4

[image]

Can any row of there, e.g. the one pointed out by the red rectangle be my Bitcoin Wallet address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern bitcoin wallets generate a fresh address for each transaction for better privacy. These addresses are generated deterministically, which is why Electrum can show them to you in advance. All of them belong to you, although you should not think of any of them as "your bitcoin address", since they are only meant to be used once.

Side note, you should probably create a new wallet now that you've tied these addresses to your online identity and to each other.

Comment: Thank you. By online identity, do you mean this stackexchange user account?

Comment: @JJJohn Yes, even though you post anonymously it's still not a good idea to reveal your bitcoin wallet addresses.